# Use of same after noun

Tags: meaning

Should I use same before noun always ? I mean can I use it after noun ? Like ;

> I have the same computer as yours

Or

> I have the computer same as yours.

Comment: After the noun it has to be _[a computer] the same as yours_. The first example should be _I have the same computer as you [have]_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second sentence could only be understood as

> I have the computer (which is the) same as yours.

It is quite common to hear sentences like

> I have a red jacket, same as *you*.

And meaning that I am the same as you in this. It means "...and you have a red jacket too".

Your example sentence might be understood, but isn't very good or clear English.  You should *avoid* using "same" after the noun in such situations.  It would be better to say

> I have the same computer as you.